# Quotient space and group action

Tags: group-theory

Consider the quotient space $\mathbb R^n / O(n)$. The orbit of some $x \in \mathbb R^n$ would be the set of all points with length $||x||$. So wouldn't the set of all orbits be $\mathbb R^n$ itself, so that $\mathbb R^n / O(n) = \mathbb R^n$? This seems strange to me since I thought quotient spaces were supposed to have lower dimension than the original space.

I'm confused in general about how to visualize what a quotient space is, so I'd appreciate anyone who can explain this concept in simple terms and why it's useful.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n/O(n)$ is the set whose elements are the orbits of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the action of $O(n)$.  As you say, these orbits are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the form

$$E_r = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| = r \}$$

for $r \geq 0$.  Thus

$$\mathbb{R}^n/O(n) = \{ E_r : r \geq 0 \}$$

which is naturally in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$.  If you union all the $E_r$ together, of course you get $\mathbb{R}^n$, but this is true for any group acting on any set.

Comment: So if there is always a bijection between $X$ and $X/G$ then what is the advantage to defining a quotient space? It seems like it's the same thing as the original space

Comment: @D_S: it is in bijection with $\Bbb{R}$, but the natural bijection seems to be with $\Bbb{R}_{+}$ rather than with $\Bbb{R}$. vibe : no there isn't always. What D_S means is that $\bigcup X/G = X$ holds, but that's actually the case for any equivalence relation, it does not bring much information.

Comment: D_S wrote $\mathbb R^n/O(n) = \{E_r : r \ge 0\}$. The set of all  $E_r$ with $r$ positive includes all vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, so I don't see why $\{E_r : r \ge 0\}$ is any different from $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Max right, I meant in bijection with $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @vibe the set theory is what is confusing you.  $\{A,B\}$ is not the same thing as $A \cup B$.  The first set has only two elements.

Comment: Ok so from a visual standpoint, is it correct to say that $\mathbb R^n/O(n)$ is a space of spheres centered at the origin with all possible radii? Where each sphere is considered a separate object in the quotient space, so they aren't all unioned together.. Also I think $A \cup B$ does in fact equal $\{A,B\}$. Maybe whats going on here is better expressed as $\{\{A\},\{B\}}$ is not the same as $A \cup B$?

Comment: I meant $\{\{A\},\{B\}\}$ is different from $A \cup B$.

Comment: Well what you think is wrong : $\{A,B\} \neq A\cup B$ for all sets $A,B$; and it's precisely what's going on here. You have $\Bbb{R}^n/O(n) = \{E_r, r\geq 0\} \neq \displaystyle\bigcup_{r\geq 0} E_r = \Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes that's a correct interpretation of $\mathbb{R}^n/O(n)$.  And as you see, that set is naturally in bijection with $[0,\infty)$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand a little better the relationship between quotient spaces and quotient groups. So if we have a group action of $G$ on a set $X$ we can define the quotient space $X/G$ as we've been discussing. But if $X$ also happens to be a group, and $G$ is a subgroup, then the quotient $X/G$ is essentially the same object, except we don't need a separate group action since the group operation itself is the action. And the set of orbits of $X$ under $G$ are exactly the same as the cosets of the subgroup $G$. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, if $G$ is a subgroup of $X$, then $X/G$ is the set of orbits of $X$ under the action of $G$ by right translation, i.e. the set of left cosets of $G$ in $X$.

Comment: What does $O(n)$ mean in this context?